# mysql query of 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables as follow:

```
table "first"       
---------------
id     item
1      pen
2      book

table "second"
------------------
id     color
1       A
2       B
3       C

table "third"
------------------------
id     first      second
1      1            2
2      2            2
3      2            3
```

Table "third" has relationship between the "second" and "first"

I would like to query from "first" table for the "item" book which has ID=2 an check it in "third" table and get third.second column value that matches third.first=2 and then pull that values(which could be multiple) and get second.color values from the table "second"

I hope have clearly stated my question.
I have tried this but it gives error:

> **#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row**

```
SELECT color FROM `second` WHERE `id`=
(SELECT second FROM `third` WHERE `first`=
(SELECT id FROM `first` WHERE `item`='book'))
```

Comment: @sachitad I have just updated my question with what I have tried. What is this negative (-1) did you do it?

Comment: I haven't done negative marking to your question. But when you come with a question, at least show what have you tried and where are you stuck. It would save a lot of time for us and for you. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You need `JOIN` syntax, like this:

```
SELECT 
  second.color 
FROM 
  first 
    LEFT JOIN third 
      ON first.ID=third.first 
    LEFT JOIN second 
      ON third.second=second.ID 
WHERE 
  first.item='book'
  AND
  second.ID IS NOT NULL
```

for better understanding `JOIN`, read this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Comment: but I don't know if ID=2. I only know item=book.

Comment: @user2718441 - sorry, misunderstood. Edited.

Comment: thansk for the help but when I run the query, it returns "color" as NULL. Where I can see that it is not NULL. I can't post the my actual code because I have changed the table and fields name for my question.

Comment: @User84 - you can either use `IS NOT NULL` (see my edit) or `RIGHT JOIN`

Comment: @Almo Do Mundo, when I added AND   second.ID IS NOT NULL or changed it to RIGTH JOIN the server gets busy and doesn't respond until I force and restart.

Comment: I can't guess what's wrong with your server. Query is ok (syntax and sence). May be you'll try do it local?

Comment: @ Almo Do Mundo - could you write a function for this?